# Redis "Scan cursor TYPE hash" support in go-redis library

Tags: go, redis

Scan method in go-redis library takes in 3 parameters

- cursor
- match
- count

It does not provide support for TYPE.

Using go-redis library, how can I implement the following?

```
SCAN 0 TYPE hash
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send generic commands to your redis server using `redis.NewStringCmd` (or other variants for any `[type]Cmd`) or `client.Do()`.

Check the examples :

- [CustomCommand](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#example-package-CustomCommand) : using `NewStringCmd`
- [CustomeCommand2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#example-package-CustomCommand2) : using `.Do()`